# How to store graphics in a separate folder from the web page

Tags: html, css

I have the following file and directory structure:

```
site\
site\index.html
site\background.jpg
site\CSS\
site\CSS\main.css
site\Graphics\
site\Graphics\background.jpg
```

*NOTE: background.jpg is on the disk in two places.

The problem is the image does not load from the Graphics folder, only the main (site) folder.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id='main'>
    <div id='header'>
        <div id='logoCompany'>
            <img class='headerGraphics' src='Graphics\logo smaller.jpg'><img class='headerGraphics' src='Graphics\Marvelous Header3 small.png'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='contentParent' class='floatClear'>
        <div id='content' style = "text-align: center;">
            <div id='leftPane'>
                Left Col
            </div>  
            <div id='rightPane'>
                Right Col
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
    Footer      
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
.floatClear {
    clear: both;
}

.headerGraphics {
    display: inline;
}

#header { 
    background: #023489;
    text-align: center;
}

#logoCompany {
    display: inline;
}
#contentParent {    
    height: 2200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
 } 
#leftPane { 
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 0 0 10%;
    opacity: .5;
    width:40%; 
}    
#rightPane { 
    background: green;
    float: right;
    margin: 100px 10% 0 0;
    opacity: .5;
    width:40%; 
}
#footer { 
    width:100%; 
}
```

I've tried:

```
background-image: url(background.jpg) works.
background-image: url(..\Graphics\background.jpg) does NOT work.
background-image: url(Graphics\background.jpg) does NOT work.
```

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-image: url('../Graphics/background.jpg');
```

For further reference on relative file paths check out this w3schools page [html_filepaths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In the path, just include the "\" in front of anything that is inside (or is itself) a subdirectory.

If it's a file in the same folder and you use the "\" it won't work because it has been instructed to check lower (it will look at your file like it's trying to check a subfolder).  If it's supposed to be in the lower folder, just include the "\" before each of the folders (in order, of course) and before the file name.